# How do I create this new symbol in the math environment?

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

I would like to create the following symbol and use it in the math environment. I will use it to denote the barycentric subdivision of a given simplex (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_subdivision), so that X(Δ) is the barycentric subdivision of Δ, where X is the wanted symbol. Is there a method to do this or should I give up?

[image: wanted symbol]

Comment: I recommend to create a command by TikZ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a new operator using `\DeclareMathOperator` (from the `amsmath` package) and `tikz`.

[image]

You can adjust the size by changing `scale=.15`. You can also adjust line thickness by adding `line width=<width>` to the `\draw` options. Default is `.4pt` (also known as `thin`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\bary}{\tikz[scale=.15]{\draw[line join=round](90:1)--(210:1)--(330:1)--(90:1)--(-90:.5)(210:1)--(30:.5)(330:1)--(150:.5);}}

\begin{document}

Consider the Barycentric subdivision of $\Delta$, denoted $\bary(\Delta)$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun I have created `\baricentric` command for your symbol.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,scalerel}
\newcommand{\baricentric}{{\scaleobj{.538}{\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw   (225.75,135) -- (238.51,156.8) -- (213,156.8) -- cycle ;
\draw    (213,156.8) -- (232,146.2) ;
\draw    (219,146.2) -- (238.51,156.8) ;
\draw    (225.75,135) -- (226,157) ;
\end{tikzpicture}}}}
\begin{document}
$\Delta_1, \,\baricentric_2,\, \Delta_n$
\end{document}
```

[image]